# Autocompleting properties from type when creating a new object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

This seems like a complete beginner's question, but my Google Fu fails me.

In Visual Studio Code, when creating a new object of a known type, is there any way to generate a stub instead of typing in each property manually?

That is, if I have the type

```
type Email = {
  from: string
  to: string
  subject: string
  text: string
}
```

and I create a new object

```
const myEmail: Email =
```

is there then any shortcut to automatically make the stub

```
const myEmail: Email = {
  from: '',
  to: '',
  subject: '',
  text: ''
}
```

or something similar?